# Is there a way for a Lua script installed with Luarocks to find its installation prefix at run time?

Tags: lua, luarocks

Suppose that I a have a Luarocks package named `foo`, which installs an executable called `myscript`. When `myscript` runs, is there a way for it to know the path to the Luarocks installation prefix where `foo` is installed?

In particular, I would like to know if there is a way for `myscript` to access data files that have been copied to the installation prefix with `build.copy_directories`.

Comment: There is a Lua module for that written by the main LuaRocks developer: https://github.com/hishamhm/datafile. I don't know whether it's up-to-date ...

Comment: Thanks! Could you repost that as an answer?